# How do I get an absolute/fixed position SPAN to display outside of and scroll with a parent DIV?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm working on a personal website whose design is an exact replica of the Windows 9x interface using only HTML5 and CSS3 (no JavaScript). I've written 2 pages designed after Windows Explorer 98. One is a dynamically-generated file explorer that shows the contents of a directory on the site (but only if I've allowed it to show that directory) and another is a static page that will act like a downloads page for software.

When a user hovers over an icon in the file explorer, they'll see a tooltip fade into view in the middle of the icon showing the file name, file type description, last modified date/time, and file size (and for a folder, it'll show its name, the number of files it contains, and its total size). It can also show the locations of symlinks. For the downloads page, it shows the name of the software, a description of what it does, its version number, and its size.

For the most part, everything is finished, except there's a problem with the tooltips: I can't seem to get them to be able to leave their parent DIV (both #sidecontent and #window) and have them capable of moving up with the icons when the parent is scrolled (should there be too many icons to display all at once). Here's the set-up of the downloads page (the file explorer has a very similar structure):

```
<div id="window">
    <div id="titlebar">
        <div id="controlbox"></div>
        <span>
            <div id="icon"></div>
            Page Title
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="menubar">
        <ul>
<?php include(str_replace('//', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/navbar.htm')); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="withsidebar">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <img src="/images/download.png" alt="Download Icon" />
            <div id="sidetitle">Downloads</div><hr />
            <p class="sidetext">Mouse over an item to view its description, and click on the item to download it.</p>
            <p class="sidetext">All downloads include source code, unless otherwise noted.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sidecontent">
            <div class="iconcontainer">
                <a href="/something.zip" download>
                    <div class="icon hastooltip">
                        <img src="/images/icons/32_exe.ico" alt="Icon" />

                        <span class="tooltip">
                            Name<br />
                            Description: File description<br />
                            Version: x.y<br />
                            Size: 999.99 KB<br />
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the Content class and the WithSidebar ID, as well as the Window ID:

```
#window {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-image: url('/images/window-border.png') 2 round;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px; /* some kinds of windows use 1px padding */
    width: 90vw;
}

.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-image: url('/images/frame-border.png') 2 round;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
}

#withsidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Here's the CSS for the Tooltip class:

```
.hastooltip .tooltip {
    background: #ffffe1;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    max-width: 410px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 7px;
    position: absolute;  /* or fixed */
    text-align: left;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hastooltip:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

To my memory, I've tried 3 different ways to try to get the tooltips to behave how I want them, with the tooltips set to either absolute or fixed positioning:

### Relatively positioned #sidecontent

The current method I use is to set #sidecontent to have a relative position. With absolute tooltips, it allows the tooltips to scroll with it, but keeps them inside the parent. Icons on the edges have their tooltips partially cut off by the scrollbar. With fixed tooltips, they can leave the parent but can't scroll with it:

```
.sidecontent {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

### #sidecontent with no set position

With #sidecontent not having any specific position set, absolute tooltips can leave the parent, but don't scroll, and they overflow the body of the page, resulting in a scrollbar that extends past the bottom of the parent. Fixed tooltips don't overflow the body and can extend past the parent, but still don't scroll.

```
.sidecontent {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

### Putting tooltips in a relatively positioned container SPAN

The next thing I tried is putting the tooltips into a container SPAN. I modified the HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="iconcontainer">
    <a href="/something.zip" download>
        <div class="icon hastooltip">
            <img src="/images/icons/32_exe.ico" alt="Icon" />

            <span style="position: relative;">
                <span class="tooltip">
                    Name<br />
                    Description: File description<br />
                    Version: x.y<br />
                    Size: 999.99 KB<br />
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Regardless of whether or not #sidecontent has a position set, absolute tooltips scroll with the parent, but stay inside it and have weird widths (even if the container has a width set). Fixed tooltips can leave the parent and have normal widths, but can't scroll and appear to all be pushed to the left of their normal positions.

Is there a pure HTML/CSS solution for this? If not, could it be possible to have tooltips that are at the edge(s) of the parent to push themselves back so they aren't obscured or have their widths narrowed?

Comment: Could you create a small jsfiddle replica of the issue? I'd be happy to help but I'd love a live example to wrap my head around your use case (especially the scrolling scenario)

Comment: I have some examples on my testing server: [Relatively positioned #sidecontent with absolute tooltips](http://w96temp.x10host.com/test1.htm), [Relatively positioned #sidecontent with fixed tooltips](http://w96temp.x10host.com/test2.htm), [Default #sidecontent with absolute tooltips](http://w96temp.x10host.com/test3.htm), [Default #sidecontent with fixed tooltips](http://w96temp.x10host.com/test4.htm), [Absolute tooltips in a container](http://w96temp.x10host.com/test5.htm), [Fixed tooltips in a container](http://w96temp.x10host.com/test6.htm).